# How to make sure for a clean reinstall of mysql and mariadb

Tags: package-management, mysql, mariadb

I had both mysql and mariadb installed, but due to root login not happening, I have decided to uninstall it and reinstall again.

I followed the following steps

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Will this be enough to remove both mysql and mariadb completely so that no broken package problem will occur?

```
$ locate mysql

/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql
/etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld
/usr/include/qt4/Qt/qsql_mysql.h
/usr/include/qt4/QtSql/qsql_mysql.h
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/dbaccess/ui/dbwizmysqlintropage.ui
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/dbaccess/ui/dbwizmysqlnativepage.ui
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/dbaccess/ui/mysqlnativepage.ui
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/dbaccess/ui/mysqlnativesettings.ui
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/gmysqlcc:gmysqlcc.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/mysql-client.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/mysql-server.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/mysql-workbench:mysql-workbench.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/gmysqlcc-32.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/mysql-workbench.png
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/mysql
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/mysqladmin
/var/cache/apt/archives/libdbd-mysql-perl_4.033-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
/var/crash/mysql-community-server.0.crash
/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-xenial-universe/64x64/gmysqlcc_gmysqlcc-32.png
/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-xenial-universe/64x64/mysql-workbench_mysql-workbench.png
/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease
/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mysql-5.7_binary-amd64_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mysql-5.7_binary-i386_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mysql-5.7_source_Sources
/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mysql-apt-config_binary-amd64_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mysql-apt-config_binary-i386_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mysql-tools_binary-amd64_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt_ubuntu_dists_xenial_mysql-tools_binary-i386_Packages
```

Should I remove any files from the above list?

Comment: Do NOT remove files with "rm". The 1st 3 commands are enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands you ran are enough. I wouldn't rely on `locate` in this case either since that command only builds its database of files once per day and may just be listing files that have already been removed by the commands you ran anyways.